# Typescript debug for Ionic2-Angular2 application in Visual Studio code

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I am working on Ionic2-Angular2 all device (ios/Android/Desktop) app and looking for a good solution to debug Typescript for Ionic2-Angular2 application in Visual Studio code. I know it is easy to debug Node.js backend code in VSCode but ionic 2 application which is targeted to run on various platforms including desktop has mainly client side code written in Angular2-Typescript.  VSCode is my favorite editor but ready to move any open source IDE/Editor if it supports Ionic2-Angular2 and Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you debug it the same way you debug Ionic 1 applications.

See here in the cordova documentation

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/#debugging-cordova-apps